# Avro 1.11.0 migration from 1.8.2 causing Invalid default issue for enum union

Tags: java, avro

For a record, we are having a field like below

```
    {
      "name": "errorType",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "com.abc.xyz.ErrorEnum"
      ],
      "default": null
    }
```

But we are getting exception for default value

```
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Invalid default for field errorType: "null" not a ["null",{"type":"enum","name":"ErrorEnum","namespace":"com.abc.xyz","symbols":["INFO","ERROR","UNKNOWN"]}]
```

This was working well with Avro 1.8.2 but causing issue with Avro 11

Answer (score 1):

Issue was due to an old schema with which old data was serialized. Early version of avro had a bug where it allowed  "default": "null" where as "default": null was correct schema.
Newer versions stopped identifying bug as right behaviour but when we upgraded and fixed schema, we went into mentioned issue.

We had to delete old schema and rewrote in this case.